# java regex ignoring n-groups in end of string

Tags: java, regex

I have following type of string to parse. String can contain n-groups. But i am interested in 5th and 6th group only.
xxxx-xxx-xxxx-xxx-xxxx-xxx-xx-xxx-xxx

Currently working on following type of expression:

```
(.*)-(.*)-(.*)-(.*)-(.*)-(SY[A-Z0-9]+)-(N[Y|N])[-(.*)]*

    if (matcher.matches()) {
        System.out.println(matcher.group(5));
        System.out.println(matcher.group(6));
    }
```

I think with my regex, i am wondering how to ignore rest of the groups, any suggestions?
Currently if string matches exact groups it yields the result, but it it contains more groups it does not match!

Comment: What do you mean by "ignore"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex isn't matching any extra groups because you're using a character class `[]` at the end instead of a group `()`. Change it to

```
(.*)-(.*)-(.*)-(.*)-(.*)-(SY[A-Z0-9]+)-(N[Y|N])(-.*?)*
```

Also, note that if you meant NY or NN at `N[Y|N]` you should change it to `N(Y|N)` because using a character class `[]` makes it match `N|` as well.